# While creating Virtual Machine storage selection is grayed out

Tags: redhat, storage

I have created new free subscription and i am trying to create Red Hat linux virtual machine.
While selecting storage i see all the sizes are grayed out and i am not able to select any storage.

Can you please advise on it.